# How to create statistics from output of Java code?

Tags: java, statistics

> Summary: I need a function based on the output. The problem is
>   connecting Eclipse or a Java code with another software.

I'm studying Physics. I needed a code that works the following way:

- first, it declares a random number n;
- then it outputs a "winner" number (based on some rules; the code
  itself is irrelevant now I think), 20 times (but should be more,
  first I need something to record the values, though).

I have n and 20 other numbers which are each between 1 and n (including 1 and n). I want, after compiling the code once, to see the 20 values, how they are distributed (for example, are they around one particular number, or in a region, is there a pattern (this is based on the rules, of course)).

The problem is, I'm only familiar with basic Java (I used eclipse), and have no clue on how I should register for example 2000 instead of the 20 numbers (so for an n number the code should print 2000 or more numbers, which should appear on a function: domain of the function is 1, 2, ..., n, and range is 0, 1, ..., 2000, as it might happen that all 2000 numbers are the same). I thought of Excel, but how could I connect a Java code with it? Visual interpretation is not necessary, although it would make my work easier (I hope, at least).

The code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class korbeadosjo {
public static void main(String Args[]){
Random rand = new Random();
int n = (rand.nextInt(300)+2);
System.out.println("n= " + n);

int narrayban = n-1;
int jatekmester = n/2;
int jatekmesterarrayban = jatekmester-1;

System.out.println("n/2: " + jatekmester);
for(int i=0; i<400; i++){
    int hanyembernelvoltmar = 1;
    int voltmar[] = new int[n];
    voltmar[jatekmesterarrayban]=1;
    int holvan=jatekmester;
    int holvanarrayban = holvan-1;
    fori: for(;;){
        int jobbravagybalra = rand.nextInt(2);
    switch(jobbravagybalra){
    case 0: //balra
        if(holvanarrayban ==0){
            holvanarrayban = narrayban;
        }else {
            --holvanarrayban;
        };
        if(voltmar[holvanarrayban]==0){
            voltmar[holvanarrayban] =1;
            ++hanyembernelvoltmar;
        }
        break;
    case 1: //jobbra    
        if(holvanarrayban == narrayban){
            holvanarrayban = 0;
    } else {++holvanarrayban;};
    if(voltmar[holvanarrayban]==0){
        voltmar[holvanarrayban]=1;
        ++hanyembernelvoltmar;
    }
    break;

    }if(hanyembernelvoltmar==n){
        System.out.println(holvanarrayban+1);
        break fori;
    }}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> basic Java (I used eclipse)

Unrelated.

I could only find two prompts in your question:

> How to create statistics from output of Java code?

You are likely not wanting to get the output alone. Use those numbers in your Java program to find what you want and output it.

How did you store 2000 values? An array, list, queue...? So also iterate on that data structure and generate the statistics you need.

> I thought of Excel, but how could I connect a Java code with it?

[There is this site.](https://www.google.com.br/)

Comment: I can easily change the output based on the possible solution. I wrote "basic Java" to avoid getting advices I wouldn't understand, and mentioned Eclipse if it has a feature in it (although I doubt it). What I need is the output numbers only (they are in [0,n], being the "winners"), and to see the pattern in them (as far as from repeating for the same n 20 times I can see, they tend to be on the two ends (close to 0 and close to n), but I would be happier if I had 2000 values).

Comment: You should share the code. As a suggestion, you could output 2000 values (for instance) to a text file, separating them with '\n' and copy and paste that in MS Excel (giving you 2000 rows to work with). Seems like what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I can share it, but I named the variables in my own language to work faster (and also probably not efficient, but easy to understand even for someone who has never written a code yet (as this code might be shown to others)). Meanwhile I have checked, which surprised me, that Eclipse can print up to at least 400 lines. That makes my work much easier, and Excel still remains my choice then.